# HTTP request through https Proxy in Go doesn't work

Tags: go, ssl, https, proxy, request

I'm going to send http request via ssl proxy in Go.
Unfortunately, it always fails. Here is my code I have tried.

```
proxyUrl, err := url.Parse("https://" + proxyURLStr)

transport := &http.Transport{
    Proxy: http.ProxyURL(proxyUrl),
}

//adding the Transport object to the http Client
client := &http.Client{
    Transport: transport,
    Timeout:   60 * time.Second,
}

request, err := http.NewRequest("GET", "https://test.com", nil)
if err != nil {
    log.Print("Create Request Error - test.com ")
    return -2, invalid_data
}

random_agent := browser.Random()
request.Header.Set("User-Agent", random_agent)

// Make request
response, err := client.Do(request)
if err != nil {
    log.Println(err)
    current := time.Now()
    elapsed := current.Sub(start)
    log.Printf("test.com is not available. %02d, %02d ", int(elapsed.Minutes()), int(elapsed.Seconds()))
    return -2, invalid_data
}
```

I get this error:

> net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)

I coded the same function in Python and tested it — works good.
But the Go code does not work.

Comment: What error did you get? You didn't include the actual client.Do(request) call, does it fail there, or does it fail at request creation?

Comment: It's timeout error, I test again and then paste the error string here.

Comment: I'v got this error.
"net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)"

Comment: Add the request call to your code.

Comment: Are you sure that the proxy URL is `https://` and not `http://`? HTTPS is typically tunneled via `http://` proxy (single end-to-end-encryption through proxy-generated tunnel), not via `https://` proxy (connection to proxy is additionally encrypted, not only connection from client to server).

Comment: the proxy is support https, and tested it with python, it works good.
but golang doesn't work.

Comment: Uhm, just to be precise: It is your code that is not working, not Go.

Comment: Paste your Python code maybe we'll spot the difference

Comment: Furthermore, this is just a code excerpt. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @wagdev any solution you found for this? facing same issue. client in python is working